# How to do video conferencing using WebRTC in android?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, webrtc, video-conferencing

I wanted to do a demo application of video conferencing using webrtc in android.I found some link for video conference using webrtc but its just for one to one not one to many.

Comment: refer https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/broadcast/#440548991085813

Comment: thanks @VirRajpurohit but its for node js i want for android. Can you please give me some link as same as for android as well if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my video consultation app, if you want to add multiple users to video calling using Webrtc, you have to modify the opensource Webrtc project according to your need, which is not quite easy.

So I have implemented [Appear.in](https://appear.in/) inside my Android Webview, which works very fine, I can add upto 8 users in a single room. Its absolutely free of cost until you buy an specific room.

Appear.in also uses Webrtc for their video calling, they have optimized it very well. Video & Audio quality is good.

The only thing, you have to do before rendering the webview, ask Camera & Microphone permission from user(Above 6.0).

Try this, I think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help @AshishGupta, is there any api for creating new room in appear.in ?

Comment: Yeah, but its not opening in webview after giving all runtime permission as well as websettings. Camera is not opening in webview.

Comment: set WebChromeClient like this: wv1.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }}

Comment: Okey now working thanks but still chat functionality is not working as same as web browser. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great to hear that, Debug your webview using Google Chrome, there will be some javascript errors.

Comment: Ok now both chat and video working but it would be more preferable to do it with webrtc because in appear specific users are come up in room, Yeah but thanks for alternative suggestion.I appreciate your answer.

Comment: but as i mentioned in my earlier comment that it would be more preferable to done with webrtc because in appear only 4 member can do video conferencing.